# batch file load balacing code query

Tags: networking, batch-file

I am trying to run a bat file code from the following reference:

[Detecting batch IP conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15478470/detecting-batch-ip-conflict)

however, i am getting an error:
TRUE - invalid alias verb
-1 was unexpected at this time.

Could someone kindly explain this to me please. thanks. sample code attached below

```
     @echo off
    setlocal

    :: Host to ping
    set primary=x.x.x.1
:: Ping with options (1 ping sent per loop, wait 500 ms for timeout)
set ping_options=-n 1 -w 500
:: Fail over after x ping failed responses
set fail_limit=5

:loop

    :: Ping x.x.x.1.  Test for "reply from".  If success, set failures=0; otherwise, increment failures
( ping %ping_options% %primary% 2>&1 | find /i "reply from" >NUL && set failures=0 ) || set /a "failures+=1"

:: If failures >= limit, switch IP
if failures GEQ %fail_limit% call :switch

:: Pause for a second and begin again.
ping -n 2 0.0.0.0 >NUL
goto loop


:: Switch subroutine
:switch

:: Get current IPv4 address
for /f "tokens=2 delims={}," %%I in ('wmic nicconfig where ipenabled="TRUE" get ipaddress /format:list') do set IP=%%~I

:: If the last character if the current IP is 1, switch to 2 (or vice versa)
if %IP:~-1%==1 ( set other=%IP:0,-1%2 ) else set other=%IP:0,-1%1

:: Perform the switch
netsh int ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection" source=static address=%other% mask=255.255.255.0 gateway=none
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is escape the equal sign in the wmic command.

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims={}," %%I in (
    'wmic nicconfig where ipenabled^="TRUE" get ipaddress /format:list'
) do set IP=%%~I
```

Comment: hi does that mean that ipenabled not equals to true?

Comment: @LionelKoh, no. The command part of the `for /f` command is "affected" by the way the parser works. The caret before the equal sign is a escape character, signaling the parser the next character should not be parsed, but included as is. Without it, the equal sign is removed from command and the "Verb" error is generated. Without the equal sign (that gets removed), the "TRUE" clause is interpreted as another command to wmic.

Comment: hi could u kindly explain this line to me also please. thanks for your help

if %IP:~-1%==1 ( set other=%IP:0,-1%2 ) else set other=%IP:0,-1%1

Comment: @LionelKoh,If you run the `wmic` command alone, you will get a list of the ip addresses in the machine. This list is feed to the `for` command. For each line in the output of `wmic`, using the characters `{},` as delimiters (points where the string is cut in pieces), take the second token (piece), store it into %%I and execute the code following the `do`. And remember all this is done for each of the lines in the inner command output (wmic). If it returns more than one line, the iteration for the second one and following will overwrite the value stored in `%IP%`.

Comment: your help is very much appreciated